# last-modified field and download file

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I have a simple example:

```
include <curl/curl.h>
char tmp[] = "/var/tmp/tmp";
char fullpath[] = "/var/tmp/test";
FILE* fp;
CURL* curl;
char bufferError[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
CURLcode result;

int main() {
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    fp = fopen(tmp, "wb");
    char url[] = "http://10.100.1.5/promorolik/Skoro_Shrek_4_obrez.mp4";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, bufferError);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
    rename(tmp, fullpath);
    return 0;
}
```

How to set for download file "test" attributes from file in server ? ( create time for file  from last modified field ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You get this information by first asking for it with the [CURLOPT_FILETIME](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTFILETIME) option to curl_easy_setopt() and after the transfer you extract the time of the document with the [CURLINFO_FILETIME](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOFILETIME) option to curl_easy_getinfo() and set it on the local file with utime().

Done!